# How to add Sticky Notes, Insert Text at cursor, .. Annotations in existing PDF file using iTextSharp with C#?

Tags: c#, itext

I want to add Annotations comment in existing PDF file using iTextSharp with C#.

Please give sample code to add Annotations in existing PDF file.

Here PS Script for my Annotation:

```
[/Contents (My Text contents) /Rect [100 600 150 550] /SrcPg 1 /Title (My Title text) /Color [0 0 1] /Subtype /Caret /ANN pdfmark
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iText(Sharp) example [TimetableAnnotations1.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=148) / [TimetableAnnotations1.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter07&ex=TimetableAnnotations1) from chapter 7 of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) shows how to add annotations to existing PDFs in general.

The central code is (in the C# example):

```
rect = GetPosition(screening);
annotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateText(
    stamper.Writer, rect, movie.MovieTitle,
    string.Format(INFO, movie.Year, movie.Duration),
    false, "Help"
);
annotation.Color = WebColors.GetRGBColor(
    "#" + movie.entry.category.color
);
stamper.AddAnnotation(annotation, page);
```

where `stamper` is a `PdfStamper` working on your PDF file; `movie` is a data structure the example retrieves title, text and color of the annotation from.

`PdfAnnotation` offers multiple other `Create...` methods to create other types of annotations.

Comment: “CreateText” method is used to add sticky notes, similarly what is method to create “Insert Text At Cursor” annotation?

Comment: Otherwise there is possible to run Acrobat JavaScript code via iTextSharp? Because there is option to add annotation with there  types by using JavaScript,

Example JavaScript code to add **“Insert Text At Cursor”** Annotation:

`this.addAnnot({page: 0, type: "Caret", rect: [0,0,100,100], name: "ann1", author: "tsR", contents: "Annotation Content"});`

Comment: Itext is not a Javascript interpreter. It only offers a Java API for PDF Manipulation.

Comment: k fine, what is the way to add **"Insert Text At Cursor"** Annotation in PDF file?

Comment: I was saw the **"CreateText"** method in the source code they have used below line `"annot.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.TEXT);"`, i think `PdfName.TEXT` is used to define the annotation type is simple Note Annotation. like `PdfName.???` what is the name for **"Insert Text At Cursor"** Annotation? Any idea?

Comment: You might look for PdfName.CARET or use `new PdfName ("Caret")`

Comment: Ya i got it i am used `new PdfName("Caret")` in the source code. i am changed the source code `"annot.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.TEXT);"` into `"annot.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, new PdfName("Caret"));"` it's working fine.

Comment: hi i am having one more query. while i am adding this annotation i am getting **"^"** symbol display in Acrobat 7 and lower version. but while using above version 9, i am getting **"Perpendicular"** symbol view. So i want only **"Perpendicular"** symbol view in all the version. please give me any idea.

Comment: According to the PDF specification, *a caret annotation is a visual symbol that indicates the presence of text edits* but it does not enforce a specific visual representation. If you want a specific visualization, the caret annotation might not be the annotation you really want.

Comment: oh fine, i am agree with your point. it's true. but after adding annotation using iTextShapr, i used Acrobat 9 or above version to open and edit some thing in that PDF file, i am get that **"Perpendicular"** symbol even i am open that PDF file using the Acrobat 7 or lower version.

Comment: Most likely Acrobat adds a specific appearance stream to the annotation. You can add appearance streams using iText, too. That doesn't guarantee anything, though, because by the specification *individual annotation handlers may ignore this entry and provide their own appearances.*

Comment: hi i am having one problem after adding annotation in the PDF file using iTextSharp, i am used Acrobat to Add Comment Enable option, but i am getting error as "You do not have permission to write to this file"

Comment: Does the *Add Comment Enable option* rely on "Reader-enabling" the document? In that case you are out of luck. Reader-enabling happens by means of usage right signatures. Only Adobe software has the private key required to apply such signatures.

Comment: So can i go with Acrobat SDK to add annotation? because while using Acrobat to add Annotation i am able to add "Add Comment Enable"

Comment: Fine!! Can i know what is reason for i am unable to add "Add Comment Enable" using Acrobat, after adding Annotation to PDF using iTextSharp?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Hi mkl,Simple just i was taken one PDF file and added some more Annotation in that PDF, after Adding Annotation i goto Acrobat to Add "Enable for commenting in Adobe Reader". on that time i am getting the error message as **"You do not have permission to write to this file"**

Comment: That sounds like the file also has been protected (by password or whatever). If you want a more definite answer, supply the PDF in all relevant stages.

Comment: Hi, I got the solution for that problem, I was used  **PdfStamper** method to save my PDF file, in that previously I was used **PdfStamper(PdfReader reader, OutputStream os)** only, I was not enabled Append as _“True”_, now I am set **PdfStamper(PdfReader reader, OutputStream os, char pdfVersion, boolean append)** append to _“True”_ , now I am able to add **“Enable for commenting in Adobe Reader”** using Acrobat. i hope that i am in correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
rect = GetPosition(screening);
```

can someone plz explain why is this is used..is there any way to find the current cursor position (top,bottom,height,width)

as with the annotation,

```
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Test.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
        doc.AddDocListener(writer);
        doc.Open();

        doc.Add(new Annotation("annotation", "The text displayed in the sticky note", 100f, 500f, 200f, 600f));
        doc.Close();
```

this works fine to me..