# Adding sticky note to existing PDF. losing original PDF content

Tags: c#-4.0, annotations, itext

I'm trying for some time now to add a sticky note to a existing PDF, but after adding the sticky note the original content and all the pages are lost. What am I missing? I know there must be a loop through all the pages but when I use a singel page document the content of the original document is also lost.
This code is partial the code found in other questions but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (Document doc = new Document())
        {

            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("D:\\Test paginas 3.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
            doc.Open();

            float height = writer.PageSize.Height;                         
            float width = writer.PageSize.Width;                                            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect1 = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(width - 120,height-120,width - 20, height - 20);
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect2 = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(width ,height-150 ,width +150 , height-50);
            String title = "Titel van sticky note";
            String contents = "inhoud van sticky note";

            PdfAnnotation text = PdfAnnotation.CreateText(writer, rect1, title, contents, true, "Comment");
            text.Color = new BaseColor(252, 251, 0);
            text.Name = "text";

            PdfAnnotation popup = PdfAnnotation.CreatePopup(writer, rect2, null, true);

            popup.Put(PdfName.PARENT, text.IndirectReference);

            text.Put(PdfName.POPUP, popup.IndirectReference);

            writer.AddAnnotation(text);
            writer.AddAnnotation(popup);

            doc.Close();
            writer.Close();
       }

  }
```

Comment: You are writing to the file that you want to read from. I don't see any PdfReader in your code. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/18636963/766786 and other duplicate questions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don's see a PDFreader in the https://stackoverflow.com/q/18636963/766786 example. Could you please show how to implement the reader in the provided code?

Comment: Click on the links in the answer to see the full code.

Comment: I'm very sorry but there is no PDFreader in stackoverflow.com/q/18636963/766786

Comment: There is. The answer of mkl gives a short code snippet, and at the top of mkl's answers there is a link to the full code example on the iText website.

Comment: TimetableAnnotations1.java/.cs

Comment: Thanks, I didn't look at that other page. How can I make the output file the same as the input file?

Comment: Not. You write to a different file. When you are done writing and you have closed the documents, then you can rename (overwrite) the new file to the old file name, but that is outside the scope of the iText part of your code.

Comment: ... or you first read the file into a `byte[]`, then initialize the `PdfReader` from that `byte[]` and let the `PdfStamper` replace the original file. But beware, if the code fails with some exception, your original file is gone for good.

Comment: Exactly. That's why writing to a different file is a safer operation.

Comment: *Trying for some time* is more costly than *reading the documentation*. Next time read the documentation first to safe time. Look at table 6.1 in this chapter: https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/d/3645210-8560-4e6d-9b03-3f9aca1921a5/samplechapter6.pdf and you'll  know that you should never use `PdfWriter` in this case, but always use `PdfStamper` (and why on earth would you use `PdfDocument` in iText 5? Are you mixing iText 7 code with iText 5 code? Then why not use iText 7 to start with?